# No result displayed in retrieving User data in facebook iFrame application using users_getInfo()

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

I'm writing a Facebook iframe/Facebook Connect application with PHP client library and in one of the pages, I need to retrieve the user's current location, either city or country.

I have added "Request for Permission" for all possible data in my index file.

```
 $user_id = $facebook->require_login($required_permissions = 'user_location,publish_stream,email,read_stream,user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_status);
```

This is the code I am using in  my application,

```
 $userInfo = $facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($user_id, array('current_location'));
var_dump($userInfo);
$location = ($userInfo[0]) ? $userInfo[0]['current_location'] : $userInfo['current_location']; 
echo "UserInfo : ".$location;
```

The result of var_dump($userInfo) is `string(0)""` and echo of $location is empty.

Please someone help  me.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that. Now I have edited the question. The error occurs while I try to get the data in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you made an error when copying the example.  You have the method signature wrong.

```
// Your version
$facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($user_id,'last_name','first_name');

// From the example
$facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($uid, 'last_name, first_name');
```

See the difference?  It's only two parameters - the 2nd is a comma-separated list of field names.

So, since you are not correctly requesting the `first_name` field from the API, it's not available in the response.

Hence the error when trying to read it.

Comment: Ok, Now I have changed as you have mentioned. But still I get the same error. `string(0) "" Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in C:\xampplite\htdocs\FacebookQantas\deals.php on line 67` where line number 67 is `$data['last_name'] = $user_details[0]['last_name'];` Please help me

Comment: Does your application have permission to read this data for the given uid?

Comment: I am trying to read my details only, trying to display my name and location details. So I thought no permissions needed.
How to get permissions for my appln to read such data?

Comment: I tried to check if I have permission, by useing the following code snippets:
`$permission = $facebook->api_client->call_method('Users.hasAppPermission',array('uid'=>$user_id));` and `$result = $facebook->api_client->users_hasAppPermission('name',$user_id);`
Again no answer is displayed in both the cases. Not even a zero.

Comment: Now I have added "Request for Permission" for the appln: `$user_id = $facebook->require_login($required_permissions='user_location,publish_stream,email,read_stream,user_about_me,user_activities,user_events,user_groups, user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_status,friends_events,friends_groups');` and used the code `$userInfo = $facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($user_id, array('current_location'));$location = ($userInfo[0]) ? $userInfo[0]['current_location'] : $userInfo['current_location'];echo $location; ` to get the location,but still no positive results :-( No errors no answer

Comment: You should move all of this into your question or just open a new one.